# Why is the son of אסנ״ת משגע״ח called a sinner?

Tags: children-parenting, sin, sexuality, ezekiel--the-book, tractate-nedarim

[The *Bavli*, *N'darim* 20:2](http://www.e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=2083), reads:

> וברותי מכם המורדים והפושעים בי אמר רבי לוי אלו בני תשע מדות בני אסנ״ת משגע״ח בני אימה בני אנוסה בני שנואה בני נידוי בני תמורה בני מריבה בני שכרות בני גרושת הלב בני ערבוביא בני חצופה איני והאמר רבי שמואל בר נחמני אמר רבי יונתן כל אדם שאשתו תובעתו הויין לו בנים שאפילו בדורו של משה רבינו לא היו כמותם שנאמר הבו לכם אנשים חכמים ונבונים וכתיב ואקח את ראשי שבטיכם ולא כתיב נבונים וכתיב יששכר חמור גרם וכתיב מבני יששכר יודעי בינה לעתים ההיא דמרציא ארצויי

Or, in my own, loose translation:

> "I will pick from among you the rebels and those who deliberately sin against me" [[*Y'chezkel* 20:38](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1220.htm#38)]. Rabbi *Levi* said:
>
> > These [mentioned in the above-quoted verse] are the sons of nine מדות‎(?): the sons of [things whose acronym is] אסנ״ת משגע״ח: the sons of fear, the sons of a forced woman, the sons of a hated woman, the sons of נידוי-type excommunication, the sons of exchange, the sons of argument, the sons of drunkenness, the sons of a woman divorced by the heart, the sons of mixture, the sons of a brazen woman [who duns her husband for intercourse].
>
> Is that a fact? But Rabbi *Sh'muel b. Nachmeni* said that Rabbi *Yonasan* said:
>
> > Any man whose wife duns him is having sons like whom weren't even in the generation of our leader *Moshe*….
>
> Ah, but that's where she attracts him [without outright dunning him].

See the commentaries and *Orach Chayim* 240:3 for the exact interpretations of these "sons", but, roughly, they're the product, the offspring, of intercourse in which the man was thinking of another woman, or in which the man was drunk, or other such examples.

I understand that [actions have consequences and that a child can have a status](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18375) of, for example, *mamzer*, with the (slight) loss of privileges thereunto appertaining, because of the intercourse of which he's a product. No problem. But how can he be, or why is he, called a *sinner* ("the rebels and those who deliberately sin against me") based on the intercourse of which he's a product? He hasn't sinned.

Comment: D'oh. Now I see that the _Ran_ (on the page, s.v. "בני אימה") alludes to an answer ([Michoel's, below](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26711)) to my question. Should've seen that before I asked. Everyone should downvote this question. `:-/`

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65434

Comment: Related (in that it's about the same passage): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/88941

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that the description of such a child as “rebellious” and “transgressor” is not in reference to the *parents'* wrongful conduct at the time of intercourse, but rather to the *child's own* predisposition to future sin as a result of this. The Zohar (See Zohar II, 204b; III, 80-82, explained in the [end of the 2nd chapter of Tanya](http://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7881/jewish/Chapter-2.htm#footnoteRef24a7881)) writes that during intercourse, the soul of the child is drawn down, and that pure thoughts and intentions at this moment are essential in bringing down a pure and holy soul. Therefore, improper conduct at this time can result in a child who is more prone to sin.

[Incidentally, the Beis Yosef (OC 340) quotes the opinion of the Ravaad who renders “בני” as “people who”, and understands it as referring to the parents and not the child. As for your proof against this, I would suggest that he understands that if R' Yonosan has such positive things to say about the children of such a union, he would not consider the parents to be sinners.]

Comment: +1 and thank you! Does _Tanya_ or the _Zohar_ refer specifically to this _g'mara_? (_Tanya_ doesn't seem to, according to the page you linked to anyway.)